# Servlet requests

Tags: java, servlets

in Servlet which types of requst (protocols)will handle. ?

i mean , http, https,

Comment: Servlets can handle http and/or https.

Answer (score 3):

The servlet framework is designed to be more general than that - in theory, a servlet container *could* handle requests for Finger, Gopher, FTP etc. That's why we have `HttpServlet` as a subclass of `GenericServlet` which implements `Servlet`. (`HttpServlet` is designed to handle https as well as http.)

In practice, I don't think I've seen *any* production servlets handling non-http(s) traffic, although I dare say they exist :) (Although I've just found this [finger implementation](http://www.mscs.mu.edu/~doug/Dist2000/servlets/FingerServlet.java).)

Comment: +1. Additionally, I'd like to add that the container does not have a separate implementation class for HTTPS. The decryption of the SSL traffic occurs much before the HTTP payload is parsed by the container.

Answer (score 0):

HTTP and HTTPS has nothing different to the servlet container after the connection establishes, so both HTTP and HTTPS are handled by Servlet.